# Hover on Div to Display Hidden Content

Tags: css

I have been trying to show a hidden div on the hover of another div and I cannot understand why it does not work.
I have a fiddle. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StudentRik/jbcnwvqx/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="mcs-div">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="Napit Graphic" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="mcs-div-content">
      <p>
        Ut arcu enim, dictum quis ultrices id, sagittis eget nulla 
      </p>
    </div>
```

I have tried all the selectors in the hidden div to be displayed, but nothing is working.

CSS:

```
    .mcs-div-content {
     display: none;
    }
    .mcs-div:hover .mcs-div-content {
     display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why this isn't working, try removing the ":hover" from the CSS rule and look at it again.

`.mcs-div-content` isn't *contained inside* `.mcs-div`, so that rule will never actually find any elements that fit it. Try replacing the second rule with:

```
.mcs-div:hover + .mcs-div-content {
    display: block;
}
```

The `+` means "next-sibling element".

Answer (score 0):

Add "~":

```
.mcs-div-content {
    display: none;
}
.mcs-div:hover ~ .mcs-div-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

mcs-div-content not is a child of mcs-div  [try](http://jsfiddle.net/51249y1u/)

```
<div class="mcs-div">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="Napit Graphic" />
  </a>


   <div class="mcs-div-content">
    <p>
      Ut arcu enim, dictum quis ultrices id, sagittis eget nulla 
    </p>
</div>

  </div>
```